# Assigning anchor tag on search bar results

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, input, uisearchbar

So, I have this simple search bar and problem is that I need an anchor tag on every object's name value to link their profile pages. How can I do that? I tried to do it with appendChild() but still can't reach it.

```
// JavaScript
 const users = [
  {name: "fabien potencier"},
  {name: "andrew nebitt"},
  {name: "taylor otwell"},
  {name: "egoist"},
  {name: "hugo giraudel"},
  {name: "thibault duplessis"},
  {name: "juho vepsalainen"},
  {name: "nelson"},
  {name: "alex crichton"},
  {name: "jongleberry"}
];

const searchInput = document.getElementById("searchBox");
const list = document.getElementById("list");

function setList(group){
  clearList();
  for(let person of group){
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    item.style.color = "white";
    const text = document.createTextNode(person.name);
    item.appendChild(text);
    list.appendChild(item);
  }
  if(group.length === 0){
    noResults(); 
  }
}

function clearList(){
  while(list.firstChild) {
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
  }
}

function noResults(){
  const item = document.createElement("li");
  const text = document.createTextNode("No results found");
  item.appendChild(text);
  list.appendChild(item);
}

searchInput.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  let value = event.target.value;
  if(value && value.length > 0) {
    value = value.trim();
    setList(users.filter(person => {
      return person.name.includes(value);
    }));
  }else {
    clearList();
  }
});
```

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="header">
        <i class="fab fa-github github-icon"></i>
        <input autofocus type="text" id="searchBox" class="search-box" placeholder="Search For User" autocomplete="off" name="search"><i class="fas fa-search search-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group" id="list" style="list-style-type: none;"></ul>
```

or, can I link local files in the "a" tag?

Comment: What is the generic URL pattern that you want to link to? It is simply a matter of creating and appending an anchor element to `item` instead of appending a text node.

Comment: @Terry actually, I need to link own local file for every option. but if it's not possible, I'll use github to upload those files, and then I'll get their URLs from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you aren't sure about how to create and append an anchor `<a>` element to your results, right? It is simply a matter of swapping out `const text = document.createTextNode(person.name);` and replacing it with `document.createElement('a')` and then setting its `innerText` to `person.name` and its `href` attribute to some URL that you know.

p/s: Since you're calling `clearList()` whether your `value` is non-zero or not, you don't have to call it in multiple parts of the code but simply in the input event handler directly

```js
// JavaScript
 const users = [
  {name: "fabien potencier"},
  {name: "andrew nebitt"},
  {name: "taylor otwell"},
  {name: "egoist"},
  {name: "hugo giraudel"},
  {name: "thibault duplessis"},
  {name: "juho vepsalainen"},
  {name: "nelson"},
  {name: "alex crichton"},
  {name: "jongleberry"}
];

const searchInput = document.getElementById("searchBox");
const list = document.getElementById("list");

function setList(group){
  for(let person of group){
    const item = document.createElement("li");
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.innerText = person.name;
    link.href = '/url/to/profile';

    item.appendChild(link);
    list.appendChild(item);
  }
  if(group.length === 0){
    noResults(); 
  }
}

function clearList(){
  while(list.firstChild) {
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
  }
}

function noResults(){
  const item = document.createElement("li");
  const text = document.createTextNode("No results found");
  item.appendChild(text);
  list.appendChild(item);
}

searchInput.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  let value = event.target.value;
  clearList();
  
  if(value && value.length > 0) {
    value = value.trim();
    setList(users.filter(person => {
      return person.name.includes(value);
    }));
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <i class="fab fa-github github-icon"></i>
  <input autofocus type="text" id="searchBox" class="search-box" placeholder="Search For User" autocomplete="off" name="search"><i class="fas fa-search search-icon"></i>
</div>
<ul class="list-group" id="list" style="list-style-type: none;"></ul>
```